# Search for common objects in a two circle intersection area

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, search

I'm solving a task that can be described in a series of points:

1. Two user types: `Fighter`, `Arena`.
2. Each `Fighter` is free to set their geo-location and their preferable search radius in the process of registration (later they can change these values in their settings). The search radius, as it follows from the name, is the radius within which the user can search for a potential opponent.
3. Each `Arena` object has its geo-location and time slots of availability.
4. Two fighters match if: their search circles intersect and the intersection area contains at least one `Arena`.
5. `Arena` is available to a `Fighter` if it lays within their search radius.

I'm in the process of implementing the matching logic. So there's a need in implementing the match algorithm. And I'm struggling to work out the right approach.

To the best of my understanding, everything can be reduced to looking for common `Arena`s. In other words, there could be a number of tables that would provide information on which `Arena`s are available to each `Fighter`. That's to say, for example a `Fighter` with `id` 98 has `Arena`s with `ids` 34, 57, 22, another user with `id` 17 has `Arena`s with `ids` 156, 57.

```
userId = 98; available_arenas = [34, 57, 22];
userId = 17; available_arenas = [156, 57];
```

By comparing the `ids` of available `Arena`s we can see that they have got one `Arena` in common, its `id` is 57. So I assume that based on this fact, it would be safe to say that their search circles intersect and there's one `Arena` where a fighting event may take place.

I thought that this approach could be used to determine whether `Fighter`s match or not. I would like to but I can't say whether the search based on this idea will be efficient or not and I see the following difficulty with it: all those `Arena` lists should be supported for each `Fighter`/`Arena`. So, if, let's say, some new `Arena` gets added to the DB, figuratively speaking, all those `Fighter`'s `available_arenas` lists must be immediately updated...which may also be a very time consuming operation. If a new `Fighter` is registered, their personal list of available `Arena`s must be calculated. If an already existing `Fighter` changes its geo-location, their `Arena`s must be recalculated as well etc.

Another approach would probably be to do about the same but without storing those `Arena`s `ids` in the DB. Doing all the calculations on the fly, given the `(long, lat, r)` params for a `Fighter` and `(long, lat)` for an `Arena`.

I'm sure there are some better approaches out there. I'd like to hear what you think about mine and if you know a better approach I'd like to know it too.

I'm using `PostgreSQL` 13 for a DBMS.

Comment: have a look at the PostGIS extension. With a spatial index on the point geometries and the use of `st_dwithin`, you can get your result very efficiently

Comment: @JGH Thank you for the tip, I will scrutinise the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there aren't many solutions, provided this fighter-arena structure. You may try to group your arena positions (by regions, anchor positions or similar) to see if you could reduce the weight of the search.
Another idea could be to store also an `available-fighters` list for each arena. Every time a fighter travels, it checks for new arenas and for those not available anymore, it can send them a message to be erased from the list. Then all possible fights in this arena are all possible combinations in its `available-fighters`

Comment: Sounds interesting, thank you for the idea. I also thought about grouping them in one way or another, but I find it difficult to assess how it will affect the overall efficiency. Seems like it's hard to do without trying.